# How to find a cell that contains parenthesis around a number - e.g. (1)

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

The formula I'm using is:

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(K6,"*"&{"current","(1)"}&"*")),"within 5 minutes",
IF(SUM(COUNTIF(K6,"*"&{"current","(2)"}&"*")),"within 10 minutes",
IF(SUM(COUNTIF(K6,"*"&{"current","(3)"}&"*")),"within 15 minutes",
IF(SUM(COUNTIF(K6,"*"&{"current","(4)"}&"*")),"within 20 minutes",
IF(SUM(COUNTIF(K6,"*"&{"current","(5)"}&"*")),"within 25 minutes",
IF(SUM(COUNTIF(K6,"*"&{"current","(6)"}&"*")),"within 30 minutes"))))))
```

The output is pulling any cell that contains both `current` and `1`/`2`/`3` etc.

I need it to pull only cells that contain `current` and `(1)`/`(2)`/`(3)` etc.

---

Hoping there's an easy way to make sure the formula includes parentheses!

---

**Here's an example screenshot of the expected outcome:**
[image]

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54012891/edit) to give us sample data?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Do you mean "current AND one of the numbers" or "current OR either of the numbers"? Your logic is not clear. Also, `(2)` can be notation for `-2`, so depending on you cell contents it could be a number, not text. A data sample and/or a screenshot would help.

Comment: *Added a sample table screenshot*

Comment: Use regex and UDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If VBA and UDF is ok then I advice you to use regex.

Open VBA editor (ALT +F11) and add a module.

Paste the following code and save the Excel workbook as macroactivated workbook (xlsm).

```
Function Regex(Cell)
    Dim RE As Object

    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    RE.Pattern = ".*(current and \(\d+\))"
    ' or if you want to match optional ()
    'RE.Pattern = ".*(current and \(?\d+\)?)"
    RE.Global = True
    RE.IgnoreCase = True
    Set Matches = RE.Execute(Cell)

    If Matches.Count <> 0 Then
        Regex = Matches.Item(0).submatches.Item(0)
    End If

End Function
```

Use it as a formula like:

```
=Regex(A1)
```

It will return the part it's looking for `current and [number]`

The return of the code can of course be whatever you want.
But I don't understand the logic in your question that is why I return what it is looking for

---

I see now the logic.

This will return the output as you expect.

```
Function Regex(Cell)
    Dim RE As Object

    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    RE.Pattern = ".*current and \((\d+)\)"
    ' or if you want to match optional ()
    'RE.Pattern = ".*current and \(?(\d+)\)?"
    RE.Global = True
    RE.IgnoreCase = True
    Set Matches = RE.Execute(Cell)

    If Matches.Count <> 0 Then
        Regex = "within " & Matches.Item(0).submatches.Item(0)*5 & " minutes"
    Else
        Regex = "False"
    End If

End Function
```

It multiplies the captured number with 5 to get the number of minutes.
If nothing is found then it returns `False`.

VBA and regex generally means the code in the worksheet is easier to maintain and easier to debug.

---

In order to make it react to the string with `current` and `(number)` then use this code:

```
Function Regex(Cell)
    Dim RE As Object

    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    RE.Pattern = ".*current.*?\((\d+)\)"
    RE.Global = True
    RE.IgnoreCase = True
    Set Matches = RE.Execute(Cell)

    If Matches.Count <> 0 Then
        Regex = "within " & Matches.Item(0).submatches.Item(0)*5 & " minutes"
    Else
        Regex = "False"
    End If

End Function
```

This code will look for `[anything]` `current` `[anything]` `([number])`

Comment: Same issue from @cybernetic.nomad solution - at least this is all i can think of as to why it doesn't work: "current" and "(1)" are in the same string: "if(string.tolower.current.accountemail(1)"

Comment: @max I see no reason why it would fail on that string. Although I have not even tried the code since I posted it from my phone. I will try it on my computer soon. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @max I see it now, without starting the computer. You said in question `current and ([number])`. Your string has no `and`. Is that not required? Do you mean `current` and `([number])`?

Comment: Yes! no and is required

Comment: @max then try the last code I added. If it doesn't work I will fix it tomorrow, I'm in bed now.

Answer (score 2):

If you really don't want to follow @Andreas suggestion (which is another way of saying "why didn't I think of that"), try:

```
=IFERROR(IF(FIND("current",A3)>0,CONCATENATE("within ", CHOOSE(VALUE(MID(A3,FIND("(",A3)+1,1)),5,10,15,20,25,30), " minutes"),),FALSE)
```

Caveat: it ignores the closing parenthesis, so `this cell contains current and (1` would not return "FALSE"

Comment: Holy cow that's a cool formula. That works darn well. It should capture everything I'm looking for. Thank ya man!

Comment: Update on this - it looks like it works when current and (1) are in different strings but not if they're in the same string; example: if(string.tolower.current.accountemail(1)" this returns false. Trying to use the macro code now